# Cell 1 = Cell 2, Cell 2 = Cell 1, Both have different input methods, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want 2 cells in 2 sheets to always be equal, but for either one to have their own different formulas or lists or inputs. I'm using the following code and it works, but just needs error fixing.

**Dashboard Sheet**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = "$I$20" Then
        Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("$AH$15") = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("$I$20").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

**Questionnaire Sheet**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Address = "$AH$15" Then
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("$I$20") = Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("$AH$15").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

***Please help me find the error?***

Comment: (a) You should include an `Application.EnableEvents = False` before setting the value of a cell which will trigger a `Change` event (and an equivalent `Application.EnableEvents = True` afterwards, or else you will end up in an infinite loop.  (b) What do you mean when you say that you want each of the cells to have their own formulas?  As soon as you set them to a value, they will no longer have a formula.

Comment: You have a big problem with that code. Your first block of code triggers you second block of code which triggers your first block of code and so on. And that is the classic event handler infinite loop!

Comment: (c) What error are you getting?  It is very hard to help you find the error when all you give us to go on is "I'm using the following code and it works, but just needs error fixing."  If it works, it doesn't need fixing.  If it doesn't work, give us a clue as to what is not working.

Comment: A cell can either have a formula that produces a value, or it can have an assigned value. It can't have a formula and a separate assigned value at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Application.EnableEvents = False just before you set the cell's value on each handler, so for example:

**Dashboard Sheet**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Address = "$I$20" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("$AH$15") = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("$I$20").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

**Questionnaire Sheet**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Target.Address = "$AH$15" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("$I$20") = Sheets("Questionnaire").Range("$AH$15").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Bear in mind though that setting a value will override any formula entered.

Comment: Thank you! you just saved a life!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a workbook level event to be placed in Workbook code pane:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _ 
 ByVal Source As Range)

Select Case sh.Name & Source.Address
    Case "Dashboard$I$20"
        Equalize "Questionnaire", "$AH$15", Source

    Case "Questionnaire$AH$15"
        Equalize "Dashboard", "$I$20", Source
End Sub

Sub Equalize(targetShName As String, targetCellAddr As String, source As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets(targetShName).Range(targetCellAddr).Value = source.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```